# Can I get sharelatex to remember collapsed figures/tables?

Tags: tables, floats, sharelatex

Is it possible to get sharelatex to remember collapsed figures/tables when I reopen a document?

I find it rather unproductive having to collapse figures and elements over and over again whenever I open sharelatex. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Have you posted your query on sharelatex's site?

Comment: where should I post it? could you provide a link